# search inside gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, search-engine

i want Datagridview with search facility. (using C# windows Form Application).

i want

- datagridview's first row shold have textbox providing search facility
  in each column
- other rows of datagrid will display data from Database.

what to do about TextBoxes?

my  purpose is that it should look more and more user friendly .

suggest other ideas if any....

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your data in your grid view stored someplace, and can't you instead search that data store?

Comment: i am asking about User Interface,not how to search data.  my data is stored in databse and i will search from it only.but  UI of search facility.i want like grid itself have textbox to serch and something like that.